# Python - vectorizing a sliding window

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to vectorize a sliding window operation. For the 1-d case a helpful example could go along the lines of:

```
x= vstack((np.array([range(10)]),np.array([range(10)])))

x[1,:]=np.where((x[0,:]<5)&(x[0,:]>0),x[1,x[0,:]+1],x[1,:])
```

The n+1 value for each current value for indices <5. But I get this error:

```
x[1,:]=np.where((x[0,:]<2)&(x[0,:]>0),x[1,x[0,:]+1],x[1,:])
IndexError: index (10) out of range (0<=index<9) in dimension 1
```

Curiously I wouldn't get this error for the n-1 value which would mean indices smaller than 0. It doesn't seem to mind:

```
x[1,:]=np.where((x[0,:]<5)&(x[0,:]>0),x[1,x[0,:]-1],x[1,:])

print(x)

[[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
 [0 0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Is there anyway around this? is my approach totally wrong? any comments would be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

This is what I would like to achieve, I flatten a matrix to an numpy array on which I want to calculate the mean of the 6x6 neighborhood of each cell:

```
matriz = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
   [6,5,4,3,2],
   [1,1,2,2,3],
   [3,3,2,2,1],
   [3,2,1,3,2],
   [1,2,3,1,2]])

# matrix to vector
vector2 = ndarray.flatten(matriz)

ncols = int(shape(matriz)[1])
nrows = int(shape(matriz)[0])

vector = np.zeros(nrows*ncols,dtype='float64')


# Interior pixels
if ( (i % ncols) != 0 and (i+1) % ncols != 0 and i>ncols and i<ncols*(nrows-1)):

    vector[i] = np.mean(np.array([vector2[i-ncols-1],vector2[i-ncols],vector2[i-ncols+1],vector2[i-1],vector2[i+1],vector2[i+ncols-1],vector2[i+ncols],vector2[i+ncols+1]]))
```

Comment: To clarify you do not want to include `vector2[i]` in the mean or was this a mistake in the code?

Comment: Your code computes the average of a 3x3 neighbourhood of each cell, not a 6x6 neighbourhood; was this intentional?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly you would like to take the mean of all numbers 1 step around the index, neglecting the index.

I have patched your function to work, I believe you were going for something like this:

```
def original(matriz):

    vector2 = np.ndarray.flatten(matriz)

    nrows, ncols= matriz.shape
    vector = np.zeros(nrows*ncols,dtype='float64')

    # Interior pixels
    for i in range(vector.shape[0]):
        if ( (i % ncols) != 0 and (i+1) % ncols != 0 and i>ncols and i<ncols*(nrows-1)):

            vector[i] = np.mean(np.array([vector2[i-ncols-1],vector2[i-ncols],\
                        vector2[i-ncols+1],vector2[i-1],vector2[i+1],\
                        vector2[i+ncols-1],vector2[i+ncols],vector2[i+ncols+1]]))
```

I rewrote this using using slicing and views:

```
def mean_around(arr):
    arr=arr.astype(np.float64)

    out= np.copy(arr[:-2,:-2])  #Top left corner
    out+= arr[:-2,2:]           #Top right corner
    out+= arr[:-2,1:-1]         #Top center
    out+= arr[2:,:-2]           #etc
    out+= arr[2:,2:]
    out+= arr[2:,1:-1]
    out+= arr[1:-1,2:]
    out+= arr[1:-1,:-2]

    out/=8.0    #Divide by # of elements to obtain mean

    cout=np.empty_like(arr)  #Create output array
    cout[1:-1,1:-1]=out      #Fill with out values
    cout[0,:]=0;cout[-1,:]=0;cout[:,0]=0;cout[:,-1]=0 #Set edges equal to zero

    return  cout
```

Using `np.empty_like` and then filling the edges seemed slightly faster then `np.zeros_like`. First lets double check they give the same thing using your `matriz` array.

```
print np.allclose(mean_around(matriz),original(matriz))
True

print mean_around(matriz)
[[ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     2.5    2.75   3.125  0.   ]
 [ 0.     3.25   2.75   2.375  0.   ]
 [ 0.     1.875  2.     2.     0.   ]
 [ 0.     2.25   2.25   1.75   0.   ]
 [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]]
```

Some timings:

```
a=np.random.rand(500,500)

print np.allclose(original(a),mean_around(a))
True

%timeit mean_around(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.4 ms per loop

%timeit original(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.6 s per loop
```

Roughly ~1500x speedup.

Looks like a good place to use numba:

```
def mean_numba(arr):
    out=np.zeros_like(arr)
    col,rows=arr.shape

    for x in xrange(1,col-1):
        for y in xrange(1,rows-1):
            out[x,y]=(arr[x-1,y+1]+arr[x-1,y]+arr[x-1,y-1]+arr[x,y+1]+\
                      arr[x,y-1]+arr[x+1,y+1]+arr[x+1,y]+arr[x+1,y-1])/8.
    return out

nmean= autojit(mean_numba)
```

Now lets compare against all presented methods.

```
a=np.random.rand(5000,5000)

%timeit mean_around(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 729 ms per loop

%timeit nmean(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 169 ms per loop

#CT Zhu's answer
%timeit it_mean(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 36.7 s per loop

#Ali_m's answer
%timeit fast_local_mean(a,(3,3))
1 loops, best of 3: 4.7 s per loop

#lmjohns3's answer
%timeit scipy_conv(a)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.72 s per loop
```

A 4x speed with numba up is pretty nominal indicating that the numpy code is about as good as its going to get. I pulled the other codes as presented, although I did have to change @CTZhu's answer to include different array sizes.

Comment: Nice. It's faster than my version for `n=3` by a factor of two, though it is rather highly tuned for that specific case ;).

Comment: I like this a lot. I'm on vacation right now but I will try this on my particular problem and get back to you. I want to use this for a 5000*5000 matrix and see how it does.

Comment: @nneonneo `uniform_filter` was actually the answer I used in the first iteration of this post, I am glad you brought it up a few questions ago its immensely powerful and incredibly fast.

Comment: This is veeery cool. I have a quick question. How can I understand a bit more on how the just in time compliation works? I tried replacing the formula sum()/n with np.mean() and It becomes muuuch slower. Why would this be? The thing is I also want the median. So I think the way the code is expressed helps or not the compilation? I am really new to this so pointing me to good introductory reads would be lovely. I don't know any C, I have a lot of experience in R and just starting with python so I have no understanding of compilation or related topics.

Comment: @JEquihua Writing good numba code is essentially opposite of writing good numpy code. With numpy taking advantage of the built in function is usually the way to go; however, here writing everything out explicitly allows the compiler to optimize your code to a greater degree. I think the issue with `np.mean` is the numpy function is building a numpy array (moving all data to a contiguous memory space) and then taking the mean of the copied data. The above code however is not copying any data. I would recommend reading the (admittedly sparse) numba [manual](http://numba.pydata.org).

Comment: thank you for the response. Would have to sort the vector to calculate the median? How could I do it so numba understands what I am doing and helps me? Any ideas?

Comment: @JEquihua This is probably better off another question.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to compute a 2D convolution. If you are able to use `scipy`, I would suggest trying [scipy.signal.convolve2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html):

```
matriz = np.random.randn(10, 10)

# to average a 3x3 neighborhood
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), float)

# to compute the mean, divide by size of neighborhood
kernel /= kernel.sum()

average = scipy.signal.convolve2d(matriz, kernel)
```

The reason this computes the mean of all 3x3 neighborhoods can be seen if you "unroll" convolve2d into its constituent loops. Effectively (and ignoring what happens at the edges of the source and kernel arrays), it is computing :

```
X, Y = kernel.shape
for i in range(matriz.shape[0]):
    for j in range(matriz.shape[1]):
        for ii in range(X):
            for jj in range(Y):
                average[i, j] += kernel[ii, jj] * matriz[i+ii, j+jj]
```

So if every value in your kernel is 1/(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) == 1/9, you can rewrite the code above as :

```
for i in range(matriz.shape[0]):
    for j in range(matriz.shape[1]):
        average[i, j] = 1./9 * matriz[i:i+X, j:j+Y].sum()
```

Which is exactly the same as computing the average of the values in matriz, over a 3x3 area, starting at `i, j`.

One advantage of doing things this way is that you can easily change the weights associated with your neighborhood by setting values in your kernel appropriately. So, for example, if you wanted to give the center value in each neighborhood twice as much weight as the others, you could build your kernel like this :

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), float)
kernel[1, 1] = 2.
kernel /= kernel.sum()
```

and the convolution code would remain the same, but the computation would yield a different type of average (a "center-weighted" one). There are a lot of possibilities here ; hopefully this provides a nice abstraction for the task you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

There just so happens to be a function in the Scipy standard library that computes the mean over sliding windows extremely fast. It's called `uniform_filter`. You can use it to implement your mean-of-neighbourhood function as follows:

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter
def neighbourhood_average(arr, win=3):
    sums = uniform_filter(arr, win, mode='constant') * (win*win)
    return ((sums - arr) / (win*win - 1))
```

This returns an array `X` where `X[i,j]` is the average of all neighbours of `i,j` in `arr` excluding `i,j` itself. Note that the first and last column and the first and last row are subject to boundary conditions, and so may be invalid for your application (you can use `mode=` to control the boundary rule if necessary).

Because `uniform_filter` uses a highly efficient linear-time algorithm implemented in straight C (linear only in the size of `arr`), it should easily outperform any other solutions, especially when `win` is large.

Comment: Very interesting. What conditions are the boundries subject to? I think I want the usual conditions but I didn't post that in my question. How is this excluding (i,j) itself? would you mind explaining the code a bit?

Comment: `uniform_filter`, by default, centres the window at each `(i,j)`, so that it averages e.g. a 3x3 window `(i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2)`. For values that lie outside the original array, `uniform_filter` uses a fill value which is determined by `mode`. If you don't care about incomplete windows, you can just delete or zero the first and last row and the first and last column.

Comment: It excludes `(i,j)` because of the `- arr` bit, which removes the original value from the window sum.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in `x[1,x[0,:]+1]`, the index for the 2nd axis: `x[0,:]+1` is `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`, in which index `10` is larger than the dimension of x.

In the case of `x[1,x[0,:]-1]`, the index of the 2nd axis is `[-1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`, you end  up getting `[9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`, as `9` is the last element and has an index of `-1`. The index of the second element from the end is -2 and so on.

With `np.where((x[0,:]<5)&(x[0,:]>0),x[1,x[0,:]-1],x[1,:])` and `x[0,:]=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`, what essentially is going on is that the first cell is taken form `x[1,:]` because `x[0,0]` is 0 and `x[0,:]<5)&(x[0,:]>0` is `False`. The next four elements are taken from `x[1,x[0,:]-1]`. The rest are from `x[1,:]`. Finally the result is `[0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]`

It may appear to be OK for sliding-window of just 1 cell, but it's gonna surprise you with:

```
>>> np.where((x[0,:]<5)&(x[0,:]>0),x[1,x[0,:]-2],x[1,:])
array([0, 9, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

When you try to move it by a windows of two cells.

For this specific problem, if we want to keep every thing in one line, this, will do:

```
>>> for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]:
    print hstack((np.where(x[1,x[0,:]-i]<x[0, -i], x[1,x[0,:]-i], 0)[:5], x[0,5:]))

[0 0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 1 2 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 0 1 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9]
```

Edit:
Now I understand your original question better, basically you want to take a 2D array and calculate N*N cell average around each cell. That is quite common. First you probably want to limit N to odd numbers, otherwise such thing as 2*2 average around a cell is difficult to define. Suppose we want 3*3 average:

```
#In this example, the shape is (10,10)
>>> a1=\
array([[3, 7, 0, 9, 0, 8, 1, 4, 3, 3],
   [5, 6, 5, 2, 9, 2, 3, 5, 2, 9],
   [0, 9, 8, 5, 3, 1, 8, 1, 9, 4],
   [7, 4, 0, 0, 9, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4],
   [3, 1, 2, 4, 8, 8, 2, 1, 9, 6],
   [0, 0, 3, 9, 3, 0, 9, 1, 3, 3],
   [1, 2, 7, 4, 6, 6, 2, 6, 2, 1],
   [3, 9, 8, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4, 0, 5],
   [0, 3, 1, 4, 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, 5],
   [4, 3, 8, 7, 8, 6, 8, 1, 1, 8]])
#move your original array 'a1' around, use range(-2,2) for 5*5 average and so on
>>> movea1=[a1[np.clip(np.arange(10)+i, 0, 9)][:,np.clip(np.arange(10)+j, 0, 9)] for i, j in itertools.product(*[range(-1,2),]*2)]
#then just take the average
>>> averagea1=np.mean(np.array(movea1), axis=0)
#trim the result array, because the cells among the edges do not have 3*3 average
>>> averagea1[1:10-1, 1:10-1]
array([[ 4.77777778,  5.66666667,  4.55555556,  4.33333333,  3.88888889,
     3.66666667,  4.        ,  4.44444444],
   [ 4.88888889,  4.33333333,  4.55555556,  3.77777778,  4.55555556,
     3.22222222,  4.33333333,  4.66666667],
   [ 3.77777778,  3.66666667,  4.33333333,  4.55555556,  5.        ,
     3.33333333,  4.55555556,  4.66666667],
   [ 2.22222222,  2.55555556,  4.22222222,  4.88888889,  5.        ,
     3.33333333,  4.        ,  3.88888889],
   [ 2.11111111,  3.55555556,  5.11111111,  5.33333333,  4.88888889,
     3.88888889,  3.88888889,  3.55555556],
   [ 3.66666667,  5.22222222,  5.        ,  4.        ,  3.33333333,
     3.55555556,  3.11111111,  2.77777778],
   [ 3.77777778,  4.77777778,  4.88888889,  5.11111111,  4.77777778,
     4.77777778,  3.44444444,  3.55555556],
   [ 4.33333333,  5.33333333,  5.55555556,  5.66666667,  5.66666667,
     4.88888889,  3.44444444,  3.66666667]])
```

I think you don't need to flatten you 2D-array, that causes confusion. Also, if you want to handle the edge elements differently other than just trim them away, consider making masked arrays using `np.ma` in 'Move your original array around' step.

Comment: Why does it not work the other way around, 10 being the first element again? or how can I do what I want then?

Comment: Oh, unlike matlab, the index of python starts from 0. So if you use positive `int`, the maximum index for a vector of length 10 is 9 and if you try x[10] you get an `indexError`. For `x=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`, in order to get 9, either `x[-1]` or `x[9]` will do, but `x[10]` will not.

Comment: I am going to edit my question to show what I really want to achieve. I just didn't want a long question but here goes. As I think you are misunderstanding me a bit.

Comment: Would this be fast? I want to vectorize the code because i'm working with big datasets (5000 x 5000).

Comment: @lmjohns3's answer is the best and fastest. `convolve2d()` is provided by extension `\site-packages\scipy\signal\sigtools.pyd`, it runs at `c` speed and also does not consumer as much memory.