# Fast way to take average of every N rows in a .npy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very large masked NumPy array (`originalArray`) with many rows and two columns.  I want take the average of every two rows in `originalArray` and build a `newArray` in which each row is the average of two rows in `originalArray` (so `newArray` has half as many rows as `originalArray`).  This should be a simple thing to do, but the script below is EXTREMELY slow.  Any advice from the community would be greatly appreciated.

```
newList = []
for i in range(0, originalArray.shape[0], 2):
    r = originalArray[i:i+2,:].mean(axis=0)
    newList.append(r)
newArray = np.asarray(newList)
```

There must be a more elegant way of doing this.  Many thanks!

Comment: You want to apply a function to non-overlapping *windows* of a ```numpy``` array.  Here are some SO links: [Using strides for an efficient moving average filter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7542135/2823755), [Python - vectorizing a sliding window](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18424900/2823755) - a couple of the answers look relevant,  [Divide an image into 5x5 blocks in python and compute histogram for each block](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22749434/2823755), [Elements arrangement in a numpy array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23645484/2823755) - the ```extract_patches``` answer would work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mean of two values `a` and `b` is `0.5*(a+b)`
Therefore you can do it like this:

```
newArray = 0.5*(originalArray[0::2] + originalArray[1::2])
```

It will sum up all two consecutive rows and in the end multiply every element by `0.5`.

**Since in the title you are asking for avg over N rows, here is a more general solution:**

```
def groupedAvg(myArray, N=2):
    result = np.cumsum(myArray, 0)[N-1::N]/float(N)
    result[1:] = result[1:] - result[:-1]
    return result
```

The general form of the average over `n` elements is `sum([x1,x2,...,xn])/n`.
The sum of elements `m` to `m+n` in vector `v` is the same as subtracting the `m-1`th element from the `m+n`th element of `cumsum(v)`. *Unless `m` is 0, in that case you don't subtract anything (result[0]).*
That is what we take advantage of here. Also since everything is linear, it is not important where we divide by `N`, so we do it right at the beginning, but that is just a matter of taste.

If the last group has less than `N` elements, it will be ignored completely.
If you don't want to ignore it, you have to treat the last group specially:

```
def avg(myArray, N=2):
    cum = np.cumsum(myArray,0)
    result = cum[N-1::N]/float(N)
    result[1:] = result[1:] - result[:-1]

    remainder = myArray.shape[0] % N
    if remainder != 0:
        if remainder < myArray.shape[0]:
            lastAvg = (cum[-1]-cum[-1-remainder])/float(remainder)
        else:
            lastAvg = cum[-1]/float(remainder)
        result = np.vstack([result, lastAvg])

    return result
```

Comment: I think you should remove that `-1` in the middle. It's skipping the last row.

Comment: Very clever algorithm! It gives wrong answer though when trying to average over a simple 1D array, e.g. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. The problem is the  result[1:] -= result[:-1] line. If you change it to: result[1:] = result[1:] - result[:-1] it works perfectly. It seems these two are equivalent but as I [found out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036126/difference-between-a-b-and-a-a-b-in-python) there is a crucial difference between them

Comment: @iasonas you're right, that's a pretty serious issue, also for 2D arrays... I'll change that, thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem (average of every two rows with two columns):

```
>>> a = np.reshape(np.arange(12),(6,2))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
>>> a.transpose().reshape(-1,2).mean(1).reshape(2,-1).transpose()
array([[  1.,   2.],
       [  5.,   6.],
       [  9.,  10.]])
```

Other dimensions (average of every four rows with three columns):

```
>>> a = np.reshape(np.arange(24),(8,3))
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])
>>> a.transpose().reshape(-1,4).mean(1).reshape(3,-1).transpose()
array([[  4.5,   5.5,   6.5],
       [ 16.5,  17.5,  18.5]])
```

General formula for taking the average of **r** rows for a 2D array **a** with **c** columns:

```
a.transpose().reshape(-1,r).mean(1).reshape(c,-1).transpose()
```

Comment: As a note to others looking around, this answer only works when a.shape[0] % r == 0

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

def av(array):
    return  1. * np.sum(array.reshape(1. * array.shape[0] / 2,2, array.shape[1]),axis = 1) / array.shape[1]

a = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]])

print av(a)

>> [[ 1.5  1.5] [ 3.5  3.5]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I had in mind was the following: `a = np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]])` with the result as `r = ([[1.5,1.5],[3.5,3.5]])`