# Difference between a -= b and a = a - b in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variable-assignment, in-place

I have recently applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379311/fast-way-to-take-average-of-every-n-rows-in-a-npy-array) solution for averaging every N rows of matrix.
Although the solution works in general I had problems when applied to a 7x1 array. I have noticed that the problem is when using the `-=` operator.
To make a small example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.copy(a)

a[1:] -= a[:-1]
b[1:] = b[1:] - b[:-1]

print a
print b
```

which outputs:

```
[1 1 2]
[1 1 1]
```

So, in the case of an array `a -= b` produces a different result than `a = a - b`. I thought until now that these two ways are exactly the same. What is the difference?

How come the method I am mentioning for summing every N rows in a matrix is working e.g. for a 7x4 matrix but not for a 7x1 array?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

*Note: using in-place operations on NumPy arrays that share memory in no longer a problem in version 1.13.0 onward (see details [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/8043)). The two operation will produce the same result. This answer only applies to earlier versions of NumPy.*

---

Mutating arrays while they're being used in computations can lead to unexpected results!

In the example in the question, subtraction with `-=` modifies the second element of `a` and then immediately uses that *modified* second element in the operation on the third element of `a`.

Here is what happens with `a[1:] -= a[:-1]` step by step:

- `a` is the array with the data `[1, 2, 3]`.
- We have two views onto this data: `a[1:]` is `[2, 3]`, and `a[:-1]` is `[1, 2]`.
- The in-place subtraction `-=` begins. The first element of `a[:-1]`, 1, is subtracted from the first element of `a[1:]`. This has modified `a` to be `[1, 1, 3]`. Now we have that `a[1:]` is a view of the data `[1, 3]`, and `a[:-1]` is a view of the data `[1, 1]` (the second element of array `a` has been changed).
- `a[:-1]` is now `[1, 1]` and NumPy must now subtract its second element *which is 1* (not 2 anymore!) from the second element of `a[1:]`. This makes `a[1:]` a view of the values `[1, 2]`.
- `a` is now an array with the values `[1, 1, 2]`.

`b[1:] = b[1:] - b[:-1]` does not have this problem because `b[1:] - b[:-1]` creates a *new* array first and then assigns the values in this array to `b[1:]`. It does not modify `b` itself during the subtraction, so the views `b[1:]` and `b[:-1]` do not change.

---

The general advice is to avoid modifying one view inplace with another if they overlap. This includes the operators `-=`, `*=`, etc. and using the `out` parameter in universal functions (like `np.subtract` and `np.multiply`) to write back to one of the arrays.

Comment: I prefer this answer more to the currently accepted one. It uses very clear language to show the effect of modifying mutatable objects in place. More importantly, the last paragraph directly stresses the importance of in-place modification for overlapping views, which should be the lesson to take home from this question.

Answer (score 43):

Internally, the difference is that this:

```
a[1:] -= a[:-1]
```

is equivalent to this:

```
a[1:] = a[1:].__isub__(a[:-1])
a.__setitem__(slice(1, None, None), a.__getitem__(slice(1, None, None)).__isub__(a.__getitem__(slice(1, None, None)))
```

while this:

```
b[1:] = b[1:] - b[:-1]
```

maps to this:

```
b[1:] = b[1:].__sub__(b[:-1])
b.__setitem__(slice(1, None, None), b.__getitem__(slice(1, None, None)).__sub__(b.__getitem__(slice(1, None, None)))
```

In some cases, `__sub__()` and `__isub__()` work in a similar way. But mutable objects should mutate and return themselves when using `__isub__()`, while they should return a new object with `__sub__()`.

Applying slice operations on numpy objects creates views on them, so using them directly accesses the memory of the "original" object.

Answer (score 11):

[The docs](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/) say :

> The idea behind augmented assignment in Python is that it isn't
>       just an easier way to write the common practice of storing the
>       result of a binary operation in its left-hand operand, but also a
>       way for the left-hand operand in question to know that it should
>       operate `on itself', rather than creating a modified copy of
>       itself.

As a thumb rule, augmented substraction (`x-=y`) is `x.__isub__(y)`,  for **IN**-place operation  **IF** possible, when normal substraction (`x = x-y`) is `x=x.__sub__(y)` .  On non mutable objects like integers it's equivalent.  But for mutable ones like arrays or lists, as in your example, they can be very different things.